# Suppress hyperlinks from matplotlib sphinx extension

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-sphinx

I am using the `matplotlib.sphinxext.plot_directive` extension for `sphinx` to create some plots dynamically in some documentation. In one of my `.rst` files I have the following command

```
.. plot:: plots/normal_plots.py
```

This essentially just runs some `matplotlib` code, e.g.

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

This successfully creates and embeds the plot, but right above it adds the following four hyperlinks

```
(Source code, png, hires.png, pdf)
```

If you look at any examples on the [matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/) they all have these four links right beside all of their plots.

Is there anyway to suppress the hyperlinks? I just want the plots, but don't want to clutter my document with these links every time I insert a plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two configuration options for this:

- `plot_html_show_source_link`
- `plot_html_show_formats`

Set both options to `False` in conf.py to suppress the hyperlinks.

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/api/sphinxext_plot_directive_api.html#configuration-options.